# How to update duplicated rows with a index (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I have a table, named city.

```
city_name
---------------
New York
Beijing
New York
New York
Dubai
Beijing
---------------
```

After update, I want it be:

```
city_name,   index
---------------
New York,    0
Beijing,     0
New York,    1
New York,    2
Dubai,       0
Beijing,     1
---------------
```

The pattern is like this: the first New York will be have an index of 0, the second New York's index is 1 and the third one will be 2. There are millions of rows in this table.

Any easy way to make this update?

I am thinking to solve this problem in two step.

First step:

```
@cities = Select distinct city_name from city;
```

Second step:

```
foreach @cities as @city
   update city set index = row_num where city_name = @city.cityname
```

It seems row_num is not availbe in mysql.

Comment: Do you have any other columns in the table, such as a unique id?

Comment: Yes. I have the unique id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update city cross join
       (select @city := '', @prevcity := '', @i := 0) const
    set `index` = (case when (@prevcity := @city) is null then null
                        when (@city := city) is null then null
                        else @i := if(@prevcity = city, @i + 1, 1) is null then null
                   end)
    order by city;
```

If you are familiar with the use of variables for enumeration in a `select` statement, then this is similar.  The complication is ensuring the order of evaluation for the `update`.  This is handled by using a `case` statement, which sequentially evaluates each clause until one is true.  The first two are guaranteed to be false (because the values should never be `NULL`).

EDIT:

If you have a unique id, then the solution is a bit easier.  I wish you could do this:

```
update city c
    set `index` = (select count(*) from city c2 where c2.city = c.city and c2.id <= c.id);
```

But instead, you can do it with more joins:

```
update city c join
       (select id, (select count(*) from city c2 where c2.city = c1.city and c2.id <= c1.id) as newind
        from city c1
       ) ci
       on c.id = ci.id
    set c.`index` = ci.newind;
```

Comment: Possible to do this? Fistly, select distinct city_name from city. Secondly,for each city_name do this: update city set index = current_line_number where city = @city_name.

Comment: I don't think that does what you want.

Comment: The first got syntax error. the second get this error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

Comment: In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.

Comment: @EvanLee . . . Yes, once again that weird limitation gets me.  And, you can't even use a subquery here to get around it, because it is a correlated subquery.  You need to join in the result.

Comment: update city c join
       (select id, (select count(*) from city c2 where c2.city = c1.city and c2.id<c1.id) as newind
        from city c1
       ) ci
       on c.id = ci.id
    set c.`index` = ci.newind

Comment: It works. but a bit slow, as I have 50 thounsands rows.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this using session() for storage AND comparing purposes:

```
  session_start();

  $number=0;
  $result=mysqli_query($yourconnection,"SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY city_name");

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  if(empty($_SESSION["storage"])){ 
  /* THIS CONDITION ONLY GOES THROUGH THE VERY FIRST ARRAY FETCH */

  $_SESSION["storage"]=$row['city_name'];

  mysqli_query($yourconnection, "UPDATE city SET index='$number' WHERE city_name='$cityname'"); /* STORE TO THE FIRST CITY'S INDEX 0 */

  }

  else if($_SESSION["storage"]==$row['city_name']){ 
  /* IF SESSION IS THE SAME COUNTRY AS THE CURRENT ROW COUNTRY */

  $_SESSION["storage"]=$row['city_name'];

  $number=$number+1; /* INCREMENT NUMBER FOR THE SAME COUNTRY */

  mysqli_query($yourconnection, "UPDATE city SET index='$number' WHERE city_name='".$row['city_name']."'");


  }

  else {

  /* THIS IS FOR THE NEXT NEW COUNTRY */

  $number=0; /* START AGAIN THE COUNT TO 0 IF NEW COUNTRY */

  $_SESSION["storage"]=$row['city_name'];

  mysqli_query($yourconnection, "UPDATE city SET index='$number' WHERE city_name='".$row['city_name']."'");

  }

  } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
```

I've done this before, but with different output but with the same logic. AND I use another table for storage purposes and comparing purposes. But the code above that I've made, I used session instead.

Comment: Not feasible to do so.